# z-index property doesn't work on hover menu links

Tags: css, menu

I made a menu bar, and custom effect on hover. I wanted the link text to be on top layer. Problem is that when I hover the link in menu, the triangle overlays the text as shown in example, even though I set the `z-index` of a link to 999.

```
<div id="menu">             
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">yyyyyy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">ppppppp</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">ggggggg</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">jjjjjjjj</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/z5zLL1kn/

```
#menu{
    height:50px;
    background-color:#fff8dc;   
    border-bottom:1px #ff8888;}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height:50px;
    background-color: #fff8dc;
    width:450px;
}

li { float: left; }

li a {  
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 44px;  
    display: block;
    color: #ff1636;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom:1px #ff8888;
    text-decoration: none;
    height:49px;
    position: relative;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    z-index:100;
}

li a:hover:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border: 10px solid #fff8dc;
    border-bottom-color: #ff8888;   
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-bottom:1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `::after` pseudo element is considered **a part** of the `a` element, and so changing the `z-index` of the anchor, will also apply to the pseudo element.

A quick solution would be to move the arrow pseudo element to the list item instead of the link.

[Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z5zLL1kn/5/)

```
li {
  position: relative;
}

li a {
  position: relative;
  z-index:2;
}

li:hover::after {
  position: absolute;
}
```

---

## Another solution:

As Roko C. Buljan mentioned in the comments, a more straight-forward solution can be to build the arrow pseudo element properly (the second `border` color needs to be `transparent`, instead of the background's color:

```
li a:hover:after {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #ff8888; 
}
```

[Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/z5zLL1kn/7/)

Comment: ...or simply build the arrow properly (Tip: `border: 10px solid transparent;`) https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/z5zLL1kn/7/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Write an answer, I'll delete mine

Comment: Nooooo don't delete your answer. It's absolutely correct. You could eventually add my comment to your own answer as an addon tip.

Comment: Great! This helped me solve a problem where a link wrapped in span, with `span::before` in the CSS, wasn't clicking. I fixed it with `span a::before.`