# Enlarge text-link hotspot without affecting text or page appearance?

Tags: css

Don't want any background colors or borders-- just want to enlarge the invisible link-region, above, below, right, and left of the link.

Tried changing padding, border, and margin, but they either change text appearance, (eg creating extra whitespace around the link, which i don't want), or simply don't affect the hotspot-size.

```
a {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

[This solution](https://codepen.io/johnyradio/pen/OEWjEM) is closer, but not quite there. I think a knowledgeable CSS coder could solve it.

**HTML**

```
flkasj fdlkasjd flkj sdsdj flkasj fdlkasjd flkj sdlkaj dlkja sdlkjf laksdj 
flkasj fdlkasjd flkj sd <a href="#">banana</a><span>banana</span> adfsddfa 
asdfas dfasdfasdd fasdf slkaj dlkja sdlkjf laksdj flkasj fdlkasjd flkj sdlk
```

**CSS**

```
span{
  color:blue;  /* TO MAKE IT LOOK LIKE A LINK */
}

a{
  position:fixed;
  /* color:transparent; /*  UNCOMMENT WHEN SOLVED */
  padding:20px;
}
```

Notice that i repeat the linked text `banana` **TWICE**, once for a hidden link-tag, and again for the visible text. The reason i repeat the text is to ensure the invisible link-tag is the same size as the visible text. ***Repeating text this way is acceptable for this question.*** However, might not even be necessary, depending on how this is done. (it would be preferable to *not* repeat the text, if possible).

As you can see, the "padding" on the link css is wrong-- the resulting link is way off mark:

[image]

But this proves we can put a linked area someplace besides (or bigger than) the original text, without affecting the page-rendering. Fixed positioning seems essential, but maybe a different positioning would work better. Also, maybe the `a` and `span` tags need to be nested rather than sequential.

The link-area can be made transparent, once the CSS is worked out, so that user only sees the "fake" link.

Comment: Do you have an example of your code and what you have tried?

Comment: @CliveSeebregts plz see update, thx

Comment: Are you allowed to change the markup?

Comment: @Terry yes, you can alter the markup. Eg., see how i repeated `banana` in the HTML.

Comment: @johnywhy Thanks for clarifying :) I've posted an answer, I hope it might be of use to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need a `<span>` element to do that. Using a pseudo-element will do the work for you. Let's keep your original link markup as such:

```
something <a href="#">banana</a> something
```

...then we can easily solve this by positioning the pseudo element absolutely within its parent:

```
a {
  position: relative;
  color: blue;
}

a::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  content: '';
}
```

See proof-of-concept example below. The example has a border added to the pseudo element to help you visualise how it is laid out. Remove the attribute in order to achieve transparency.

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  color: blue;
}

a::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
flkasj fdlkasjd flkj sdsdj flkasj fdlkasjd flkj sdlkaj dlkja sdlkjf laksdj 
flkasj fdlkasjd flkj sd <a href="#">banana</a> adfsddfa 
asdfas dfasdfasdd fasdf slkaj dlkja sdlkjf laksdj flkasj fdlkasjd flkj sdlk
```

---

On an additional note, you might want to hide the pseudo element using `display: none` when printed, using the `@media print` media query:

```
@media print {
    a::before {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thx for making the answer so complete, and thinking of real-world issues like printing. Before marking as answer, I'll wait a day or so, to see if anyone offers an alternate method. For example, it would be preferable to *not* repeat the text, if possible. Thx!

Comment: why is the span invisible without `color:transparent`?

Comment: @johnywhy I just realised you only want to increase the click area of the link without any visual add-ons. If that's the case, using a pseudo-element will work. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Your CSS works great by itself. However, when i integrate it with the rest of my CSS, it breaks. I'll share the CSS on codepen or fiddler.

Comment: @johnywhy That's because the selector `a` and `a::before` is extremely generic—it targets **all anchor elements on the page**. It is up to you to decide on the specificity of the selector, given that we do not know the exactly markup of your page.

Comment: I'm not sure specificity is the issue. Here's the defective integration:
https://codepen.io/johnyradio/pen/xzgpXJ

Comment: @johnywhy That's because your anchor element spans multiple lines

Comment: Anchor span must be parent to the tag-region span, which is needed for the hover to work. i'm sure the hover could be reworked to avoid the issue, not sure i can solve it. i put the hover CSS back so you can see.

Comment: issue: link isn't clickable. No doubt another conflict with hover... https://codepen.io/johnyradio/pen/xzgpXJ

Comment: link is clickable with my code alone ,and with your code alone, but not with both our code combined

Comment: Solved. Problem was link wrapped in span `<span><a>banana</a></span>`, with `.MySpan::before` in the CSS. Link wasn't clicking. I fixed it with `.MySpan a::before`. Ie, put pseudoelement on the `a` tag, instead of the span. Helped by https://stackoverflow.com/a/39314847/209942